# How to entangle 2 qubits using a polarizing beam splitter?

Tags: photonics, linear-optics

A polarizing beam splitter splits a continuous beam of photons in 2 directions:

[image]

(from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1n3hizj3c4))

[image]

[image]

(from [here](https://turbofuture.com/computers/build-quantum-computer))

I am curious and have a few related questions about using simple optics in quantum computing:

1. Is splitting a light beam by polarization a true quantum (probabilistic) effect?
2. How would one tensor two qubits using this setup to form the tensored/entangled state

$$(a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle)(c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle)= ac|00\rangle + ad|01\rangle + bc|10\rangle + bd|11\rangle$$

3. How would a CNOT gate be implemented in this setup?

Comment: Great idea, some pointers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/the-most-price-efficient-experimental-setup-involving-spdc-single-photon-counti

Answer (score 1):

You get entanglement if you use single photons (or other types of nonclassical light) instead of coherent light.

Linear optical operations on coherent states never result in entanglement. Roughly speaking, a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ passing through a beamsplitter gives a state of the form $|t\alpha\rangle|r\alpha\rangle$ for some $t,r$, $|t|^2+|r|^2=1$. Similar results hold for arbitrary linear operations (linear here means operations that preserve the photon number). With a PBS, the same thing applies, except output modes also have a different polarization state, and so you can write them as something like $|t\alpha_H\rangle|r\alpha_V\rangle$. Point being, these are not entangled states.

Note that things are different with single photons, as the evolution then reads $(a_H+a_V)\to a_{1,H}+a_{2,V}$ where $1,2$ label different position states. Or in ket notation, you can write the latter state as $|1,H\rangle+|2,V\rangle$, which clearly looks entangled.

As to whether it's legitimate to consider single photons as "entangled", I'll remind you to the discussion [in this other post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/388668/58382). The gist being that yes, you arguably can, and a standard reference here is ([S. J. van Enk 2005](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507189)).

As to *how would a CNOT gate be implemented in this setup?*: the PBS *is* a CNOT in this position-polarization encoding. Specifically, it flips the position state conditionally to the polarization.